# MATLAB - Given a matrix, output the constant factor and the new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given a matrix, output the constant factor and the new matrix. The constant is an integer and can be either real or imaginary. Here are some examples:

```matlab
i = sqrt(-1);
M1 = [2 4 6; 8 10 12];
% output:
% Factor: 2
% Matrix: [1 2 3; 4 5 6];

M2 = [1*i 4*i 5*i; 8*i 7*i 12*i];
% output:
% Factor: i
% Matrix: [1 4 5; 8 7 12]

M3 = [1 2 5; 4 8 1]
% output:
% Factor: 1
% Matrix: [1 2 5; 4 8 1]
```

Comment: You can use `gcd`. It returns the greatest common divisor. However, this function only takes two scalars so you have to loop over all elements in the matrix. It also only works with integers, but you could check if all numbers are imaginary, then `i` could be factored out manually.

Comment: Please read here on “[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)”

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function `f` like below

```
function [Factor, Matrix] = f(M)
if all(imag(M)~=0)
    s = 1j;
else
    s = 1;
end
V = unique(M(:)/s);
Factor = V(1);
for k = 2:length(V)
    Factor = gcd(Factor,V(k));
end
Factor = Factor*s;
Matrix = M./Factor;
end
```

and you will

```
>> [factor, matrix] = f(M1)

factor =

     2


matrix =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

>> [factor, matrix] = f(M2)

factor =

   0.0000 + 1.0000i


matrix =

     1     4     5
     8     7    12

>> [factor, matrix] = f(M3)

factor =

     1


matrix =

     1     2     5
     4     8     1

>> [factor, matrix] = f([2,3])

factor =

     1


matrix =

     2     3
```